# Colocar arquivo .txt local dentro de uma página local

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, xmlhttprequest

Eae, galera.
Quero avisar primeiro que não manjo muito de java e esses tipos de código, então por isso já espero não ter respostas, mas vamos lá.
Seguinte, o que eu preciso fazer, pra um projeto, é usar o texto que está dentro de um arquivo ".txt" e colocá-lo como texto em uma página HTML.
Eu andei pesquisando, e pelo que eu entendi, não tem como fazer isso pois o arquivo é local (file:///) e não está hospedado em um servidor.
Tem alguma maneira de contornar isso? Esse projeto não irá ser upado. Ele não vai ficar online, a única pessoa que vai abri-lo sou eu, no meu PC.
Mas então, caso não seja possível, eu preciso de ajuda com o código para que ele funcione online.

HTML:

```
<div id="printed"></div>
```

CSS:

```
var text_print = new XMLHttpRequest();
        text_print.open("GET", "http://www.textfiles.com/etext/FICTION/2000010.txt", true);
        text_print.onload = function (){
            console.log( text_print.responseText.slice(0, text_print.responseText.indexOf("\n")) ); };
        text_print.send();

    document.getElementById("printed").innerHTML=text_print;
```

Não preciso nem dizer que não funcionou né? hahaha
Como eu disse, não manjo de java e pá, então catei na internet algo parecido e acabei com esse código ai, mas não funciona.
Acho que não tem necessidade de explicar, mas o que eu preciso é que o texto do arquivo "2000010.txt" se transforme na div com id "printed".
Obrigado.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o Apache para criar um servidor próprio na sua máquina e assim conseguir efetuar requisições HTTP como desejado.

Comment: Olá Anderson!  Primeiramente obrigado pela resposta. Dei uma pesquisada aqui e instalei o XAMPP. O arquivo ficou com esta URL "http://localhost/teste/teste.txt".  Eu precisaria saber agora a respeito do código, pois o código acima continua sem funcionar. =/ Obrigado.

Comment: Correção: Funcionou. Eu tinha deixado a página fora do servidor local, logo, isso impedia a página de buscar o arquivo. Coloquei ambos na mesma pasta no localhost, o document.getElementByID dentro do onload, apaguei o console.log e funcionou. =) Obrigado!

Comment: achei isso mas não consegui fazer funcionar aqui.  http://www.diogosouza.com.br/2016/01/como-configurar-flag-allow-file-access.html

Comment: Aqui só no Google Chrome não funciona, IE pergunta se permite abrir conteúdo bloqueado, o Safari, Firefox e Microsoft Edge funciona. E com vc só no Mozila? Estranho!!!